# 2 empty values in a dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just a quick question on my drop down list there are 2 empty values, and then male and female, I was just wondering why these empty values appear, also I have left Gender? so, default empty is selected. Please advise.

```
public class PatientRegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your gender.")]
    public Gender? GGender
    { get; set; }

    public enum Gender
    {
        [Display(Name = "Male", Order = 0)]
        Male = 0,

        [Display(Name = "Female", Order = 1)]
        Female = 1

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <!--<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GGender, "Choose your gender:", new { @style = "", @class = "", id = "" })
       <span style="color: red;">*</span>
       @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Profession, new SelectList(Model.Professions, "Id", "Name"), new { placeholder = "", @style = "", @class = "form-control", id = "Profession" })*@
       @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GGender, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GGender)
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason for the problem**
the first empty value will come from the second parameter of this method call

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GGender, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

here you are passing an empty string to the value which must appear when nothing has been selected (I assume you already know that)

This was easy, so where the second empty value come from? 
It is coming from your property `GGender` which is of type `Nullable<Gender>` not `Gender` so actually this property has three possible values

1. Male
2. Female
3. Null **(which rendered as second empty value in `select` html element)**

**Solution** 
If you want to **not** select anything by default from the `select` HTML element
you have to change your property to following

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your gender.")]
public Gender? GGender { get; set; } = null;
```

and your call in the view to

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GGender.Value, "Please Select gender ...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the data is empty, but what you see is a text or label not value. and 
`public enum Gender` method shows it to display as this (Male or Female).

- To test - do not display even text then remove name from like 
  `display name = ""` this will not show text now.
- You can test if they have value or not by **html inspect.**

[Help example here!](http://peterkellner.net/2013/06/27/simple-dropdownlist-with-default-value-using-asp-net-mvc4-razor-and-an-htmlhelper/)

Comment: I dont have display name? @Ajay

Comment: [Display(Name = "Male", Order = 0)]   // here "Male"